# WPF Grid with Row heights * not expanding to Grid's max height

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, row-height

My WPF Grid has 3 rows (Auto, *, *) and maxHeight set to 500. When there is no content for second or 3rd row, Grid still doesn't expand to its maxHeight.

XAML Code:

```
<Grid MaxHeight="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Button occupies 30 px-->
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="SwitchGrid"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding DG1}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding DG2}"/>
</Grid>
```

Problem Statement:

- [Success] If both ContentControls are provided, they occupy equal space (~230 px) and Grid is shown to expand to MaxHeight=500 px.
- [**Failure**] If either of the ContentControls are *not* provided, the other contentcontrol still occupies max ~230 px (this ContentControl can occupy 500 px, but due to Grid's restriction it occupies only 230 px and shows a scrollbar) and Grid doesn't expand to 500 px. Snoop reveals that one of the control control size is 0, but looks like Grid is still reserving space for it. I have seen this behavior even when the Grid is placed directly inside MainWindow, hence I dont this it is related to any other container.

What can I do to make sure Grid expands to MaxHeight if any of its children need it?

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproduction of your issue.

Comment: Not sure, but I think MaxHeight only prevents the grid from using more space than you specify, it doesn't mean that it will use that space if it's not needed. If you want both controls to occupy a fixed amount of space, use Height instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the row height to a string property..

```
<Grid MaxHeight="500">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Row1Height, FallbackValue=*}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Row2Height, FallbackValue=*}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Button occupies 30 px-->
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Content="SwitchGrid"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding DG1}"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="2" Content="{Binding DG2}"/>
</Grid>
```

Then you can update it whenever you want, for example..

```
public DG1 DG1 {
    set{
        // ..
        Row1Height = value == null ? "0" : "*";
    }
    get{
        // ..
    }
}
```